# Chofetz Chaim Story

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, olam-haba-world-to-come, story-identification

Asking for someone else:

In the Artscroll "Pirkei Avos Treasury" they bring a story on the mishnah "All Israel has a share in Olam Haba." Someone asked the Chofetz Chaim if all Jews have a share in Olam Haba, why should they do Torah and mitzvos, since anyway they are guaranteed a share in Olam Haba. The Chofetz Chaim answered that it is analogous to a factory owner paying everyone, regardless of what they actually produced in the factory. But the one who did no work will have to sheepishly answer, when asked what he did in the factory, "I took a check." Is this story mentioned anywhere in the Chofetz Chaim's seforim or letters? And if so, which one?

(I know it is found in Moshe Yoshor's Hebrew biography of the Chofetz Chaim, but I would like to know if it is found in any of the Chofetz Chaim's seforim or letters that he wrote.)

Comment: A similar question was asked and deleted recently by someone else. Who asked you to post this?

Comment: Yes I thought I was also getting deja vu?

Comment: I found this on the yeshiva world News coffee room